# Seva, the fictional Greek Goddess of Destruction, in a pre-1955 book

Tags: story-identification, books, religion

My father named me after a character he read in a Science Fiction novel published prior to 1955. The character's name is Seva, who is the Greek goddess of destruction within the context of that book. Unfortunately, I never thought to ask him the title of the book before he passed away.  I'd really like to find it.  Can anyone help me ?

Comment: This is a really unique question.  Way to go!

Comment: I have to ask if you are sure it was a _Greek_ goddess, and that he got the spelling right. There's no Greek goddess Seva to my knowledge, but Shiva is the Hindu god of destruction.

Comment: Note that Seva says specifically "within the context of the book," so I am not sure any arguments based on "real world mythological facts" (to coin a phrase) are relevant.

Comment: I take it you were a troublesome infant.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the book could be [Siva](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441768369), by [Walt](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?1720) and Leigh Richmond. Note that Amazon gives the publication date in 1955, but also that all the other sources, [wikipedia included](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ace_SF_double_titles#H_Series), give 1967.

In fact, as you can read [here](http://www.davidicke.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-105809.html):

> Walter Richmond was a scientist researching atmospheric electricity,
> the electric currents between the earth and the ionosphere. Richmond
> went to Washington in 1963 to JFKs science advisor. Their papers were
> placed under the official secrets act. The Richmond's were frustrated
> that their work was being hindered (they were told to shut up) and
> they turned to fiction to express their ideas.
>
> Interestingly, the novel was renamed "Siva" a few years ago. Siva
> being the God of destruction whose statue can be found at CERN.

This is a [picture](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:CERN_shiva.jpg) of the statue.

Comment: That is the Hindu god, but it could still be on the mark if the religion was misremembered.

Comment: I know: but it seems that the book is a sort of pastiche on advanced ancient civilizations, pyramids and so on. So it could be a possibility. You can find a review (not exactly flattering) by Peter D. Pautz by searching on google books "siva walt richmond review"