# Chee Ops stations

Tags: story-identification

What is the name of the book that had the pyramids as chee-op power stations?

Comment: Could you fill-in a few more details? The year you read the book, was it a graphic novel or just words, how old was it at the time, the characters in it, anything about the style or plotting... etc.. (Eg. What language was it in)

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/762090.The_Giza_Power_Plant?

Comment: Not sure that speculative science (or pseudoscience if I'm being unkind) is on-topic here as it lacks the usual elements of science fiction/fantasy - i.e. that it has no pretensions of being true.

Comment: What is a “chee-op power station”?

Comment: @fez "Cheops" ("Χεοψ") was the ancient Greek transliteration of the name of the Pharaoh Khufu, builder of the first of the Great Pyramids.

Comment: @Buzz ah interesting, thanks! TIL

Comment: To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read the book and what books you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our [guide on asking identification questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/7957).

Answer (score 12):

[Gallagher's Glacier](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2086722) by Walt Richmond and Leigh Richmond.

[image: Gallagher's Glacier]

> In the cold corrupt system of the colony mining worlds, one man's life and liberty aren't worth much; the vital spacelanes are rigidly controlled, and it's as much as your life is worth to go against the system. But there is one man with both the unbroken spirit and the technological mastery to open the lanes and free his fellow men from tyranny. And on grim Stellamira, N.N. Gallagher builds the first resistance. His downtrodden colonists with nothing left to lose, and worlds to gain; a clever, rebellious young madame and her "entourage;" a native starship captain with a lot to learn, and a battlefield to learn it on; and a great ice-asteroid that engineering genius has transformed into a ship called GALLAGHER'S GLACIER.

The power system on the colony is based on giant pyramids:

> The solar-tap landing system was a magnificent sight, and as long as I was on Betsy Ann I never ceased to be caught into a tremendous awe and delight when it was turned on. It wasn't turned on now. Only the one beam from atop the central pyramid pulsed its broadcast power and sang its deep-throated song.
>
> There was a central pyramid supplying power on each of the three continents of Betsy Ann, I was told; those would soon be supplemented with satellite pyramids needed to create landing systems on each continent. Meantime, the equipment needed to convert Betsy Ann from a desert planet into a lush, green one could operate anywhere on broadcast power,

And *chee-ops* is the sound the pyramids make when operating:

> Then the horizon would light up again, and instead of the pale single streamer that flickered, instead of the omnipresent *chee-ops*; *chee-ops* that was the song of the tap in its normal operation, the huge, ladderlike structure of beams would flame into the sky, and the chorus of the other pyramidal structures would join into a deep subsonic roar like the after rumble of thunder, interspersed with harmonics that were more like a drum than the oboe note of the single tap.

Comment: There's another W&L Richmond book that had the pyramids on Earth be remnants of an ancient civilization's advanced power system. It could also fit the question but I think you are right because of the sound. I hadn't heard of this book but was going to post about the other. I think it had 'millenium' in the title.

Comment: @OrganicMarble If you think the other book is a possibility post it! I only have a few books by the Richmonds so I may well not have got the book the OP is thinking of. I'll upvote your answer :-)

Comment: @OrganicMarble: ah, I do have _The Lost Millenium_ and it has: _“This is the insulator,” he said, sketching a slightly truncated pyramidal form. “The proportions—about like the pyramids of Egypt. The main one will look—well, like the Cheops pyramid. The pyramid’s the insulator, to insulate the electric current from the ground. On top of the pyramid—here—will be a laser system, a coherent light beam that switches on and off in microseconds, giving a surge of power each time it’s on. The power collector and transformer and the control apparatus will be at the top of the pyramid._

Comment: Aha, on further searching of the book it mentions the sound the pyramids make: _“Shee-op. Shee-op.” The double-pulse beat through the silencer tunnels of the granite pyramids that were the Sivas’ insulators. “Shee-op. Shee-op. Shee-op.”_ So if _shee-op_ has been misremembered as _chee-op_ this could well be the book.

Comment: Sounds like they were into plowing the same ground :) OK, I'll post it, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Besides this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/286159/28516) there is another Walt and Leigh Richmond book concerning pyramids, *[The Lost Millennium](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22292)* aka *Siva*.

I read this only because it was the flipside to the A. Bertram Chandler *Road to the Rim* which I first found in an Ace Double paperback.

I don't remember much about it except that it concerned an ancient civilization on Earth which used pyramids to tap power from the upper atmosphere or space, and then things went spectacularly wrong.

[John Rennie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4144/john-rennie) was kind enough to supply some quotes and it turns out that in this book, the pyramid system also makes a "shee-op" sound.

> The double-pulse beat through the silencer tunnels of the granite pyramids that were the Sivas’ insulators. “Shee-op. Shee-op. Shee-op.”

There's a summary of the book at this [goodreads link](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/11128464).

It appears the Richmonds were fond of this pyramid power thing.

Answer (score 5):

Another instance is *Pyramids* by Terry Pratchett (1989), in which the titular pyramids are used to focus and store energy in order to halt or reverse the flow of time. The excess is flared off, making a certain sound:

> The sun rose. As the golden light spilled down the fertile valley of the Djel the pyramid flares paled and became ghost dancers against the lightening sky. They were now accompanied by a noise. It had been there all the time, far too high-pitched for mortal ears, a sound now dropping down from the far ultrasonic.
>
> *KKKkkkkkkhhheeee...*
>
> It screamed out of the sky, a thin rind of sound like a violin bow dragged across the raw surface of the brain.
>
> *kkkkheeeeeee...*
>
> Or a wet fingernail dragged over an exposed nerve, some said. You could set your watch by it, they would have said, if anyone knew what one was.
>
> *...keeee...*
>
> It went deeper and deeper as the sunlight washed over the stones, passing through cat scream to dog growl.
>
> *...ee...ee...ee...*
>
> The flares collapsed.
>
> *...ops.*

Comment: I'm opting for Siva by Walt Richmond as well - mainly because of my dupe answer from five years ago! https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189221/im-looking-for-a-fiction-book-about-pyramids/189226#189226