# Book with lasers on pyramids for electricity generation, sun flare ending the civilization, genetic engineering of pets and rebirth of civilization

Tags: story-identification, books, genetic-engineering

An ancient civilization uses lasers mounted on pyramids to generate electricity. When a sun flare causes an uncontrollable cascade which ends their civilization, some escape to space. One group, which includes a woman with a genetically engineered cat, depart in a fleet of crafts capable of nearing the speed of light. Another group, which include a man with an engineered dog, remains behind.

The man's group works to repair the damage caused by the cascade and then aides in the evolution of mankind. They even cause the flood to reduce atmospheric radiation. Later, the ships that left start to return to find the Earth renewed but occupied by a new human civilization on the brink of repeating the whole thing.

Comment: Sounds like the backstory to the Thundercats cartoon.

Comment: I'd forgotten all about this book. I'm going to have ot dig it out and read it again! Thanks, Cee and @Eshier

Comment: FYI, when I read this book it was called "The Lost Millenium" and it was in an Ace Double with a John Grimes book http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?22292

Answer (score 6):

I've never read it, but having seen one of these answers previously, it reminded me of [*Siva!*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3782250-siva?from_search=true) by by Leigh & Walt Richmond.  Previous title was *The Lost Millenium*.

[image: Cover from Goodreads.]

> The Great Pyramid of Cheops: Geometrical perfection.
>
> The Piri Reis maps: ancient cartographs that show Earth as seen from polar orbit - they have recently been confirmed by satellite photography.
>
> Myriad proofs that Earth has changed its axial tilt during near-historical times: perhaps as recently as 1450 B.C.
>
> In 1962 Walt Richmond developed the theory of the "solar tap": a source of electrical power so great that one installation could provide the world's power. In 1963 his research papers were labeled "Top Secret." The Richmonds refused to work under conditions of secrecy, but Walt worked out on his own the ideal structure for a solar tap.
>
> The Result: an exact replica of the Great Pyramid.
>
> The kind of power postulated by the Richmonds' findings makes all the anomalies of history fall into place. This book was written as science fiction. Whether the story approaches the actual beginning of our civilization is something for each reader to decide for himself...

---

There is a discussion/critique of the ideas and the book under it's original title, *The Lost Millenium* [here](https://www.goodreads.com/story/show/477512-whatever-pt-6-000-000-000).

---

It has been suggested as an answers for questions [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21434/78394) and [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189221/im-looking-for-a-fiction-book-about-pyramids/189226).

---

There is a [book search](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/608456-70s-scifi-technological-advanced-civ-destroys-pangea-s) on Goodreads that is listed as solved with this as the answer.  The original description is below.

> The premise of the book is that when the earth was all one continent, there was a very technologically advanced civilization that was sending out spacefaring colony ships but had a massive power surge that broke apart pangea. They built all of their structures from stone because metal buildings disrupted their power supply. The spacefarers came back to earth from time to time and tried to re-civilize the survivors which is why there are stone pyramids all around the world (egypt, cambodia, latin america, etc). Also, some people survived the cataclysm on a submarine called an ARK.

Comment: I read it many years ago, the flying machine shown on the book cover was called a 'car-a-pet' and this gradually faded into legend as a flying carpet